# Custom fonts iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, xcode4.5, truetype

I downloaded a couple of LCD / LED fonts from the internet, but so far have only been able to get one of them running on my iPod. They display fine on the simulator of XCode 4.5, but once I try running them on iPod, most of them fail.
I double checked to have the fonts included in the project, that the fonts get copied to the device via the bundle and all that's necessary to get them running.
Does any one have information about why some fonts can be used on iDevice and some not? What do I need to look for before downloading or buying a font?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have them listed in your info.plist?

Comment: Have you tried opening the fonts in Font Book and verifying that you're using the PostScript name of the font face exactly as it appears there when creating your `UIFont`s?

Comment: I did all that. I even tried all the other names I found in font book. I have a couple of downloaded fonts which work, and some just don't. I hope that the one I found today works. For the ones that work, is there a way to include them in IB so one could have them like WYSIWYG style in IB?

Comment: The one I found works. If some one else needs a nice looking LED font free for commercial use, check out "Transponder AOE" or look for Trana ttf on google. Direct link: http://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=transponder . The page lists the font as free for personal use, but if you visit the authors page on http://www.astigmatic.com/ , (the freeware section), he links to dafont, too. The freeware page explicitly says that all freeware fonts are usable for personal and commercial use. But I would still love to see the font show up in IB for WYSIWYG.